# DFP Banner Ads causing crashes on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-dfp, admob

We are facing some fatal crashes on the iOS devices since yesterday in our live App on the Appstore.

Below are the stack trace received from Fabrics in Crashlytics.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x186343d38 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x185858528 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1863511f8 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1863496e4 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18622f0dc _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  moneycontrol                   0x104fbadbc __28-[VCEBridge requestGGScript]_block_invoke_2
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x185cc9088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x185cc9048 _dispatch_client_callout
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x185cd5b74 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1862ebf20 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1862e9afc __CFRunLoopRun
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18620a2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
12 GraphicsServices               0x18809bf84 GSEventRunModal
13 UIKit                          0x18f7b7880 UIApplicationMain
14 moneycontrol                   0x1048853c4 main (main.m:13)
15 libdyld.dylib                  0x185d2e56c start
```

Another in the Thread  ***com.google.admob.view-hierarchy***

```
com.google.admob.view-hierarchy
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x185e5dc1c __ulock_wait + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x185ccb5c0 _dispatch_ulock_wait + 48
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x185ccb718 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow$VARIANT$mp + 36
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x185cd7038 _dispatch_sync_wait + 448
4  moneycontrol                   0x104db3bf4 GADCategories_NSString_GADPathValidation + 4334287860
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x185cc9088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x185cc9048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x185cd2e48 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 528
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x185cd37d8 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x185cd4200 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 400
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x185cdc4a0 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 644
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185f6efe0 _pthread_wqthread + 932
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185f6ec30 start_wqthread + 4
```

We are using ***GoogleIMASDK3 SDK***.

Comment: we see the same stacktrace, although it starts elsewhere for us

Comment: I'm also seeing the exact same thing in my apps.